# please help me to replace unzip

Tags: plsql, unzip

I am using unzip command in my PL/SQL script. Now I want to use pkzip without changing PL/SQL code.

Is it possible to remove unzip command and create new shell scipt named unzip with pkzip command in it.

How can I achive this?

Answer (score 0):

use the `alias` command on linux

```
alias newcommand='yourcommand -arguments'
```

so in your case it will be something like

```
alias unzip='pkzip'
```